# ionic 3 Geolocation in certain android version

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3, ionic-native

I am creating an app in ionic 3. i am using ionic native Geolocation plugin and when i am getting the current position, there is some problem.

below is my code:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private geolocation: Geolocation) { }

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ timeout: 15000 }).then((resp) => {
  this.loc.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
  this.loc.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
  this.storage.set('location', this.loc);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("error");
});
```

The Problem is when i am using this code for Android version 6, it's working fine BUT when i test it with Android version 8, I don't get the location coordinates.

Please Help.

Also can someone tell me how can i test app in different devices online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that the last Android version supported by Cordova is **7.1.1** on waiting to implement the newest versions.

And You have to know that the supported Android version is depending of your Corodova version. Every Cordova version supports an interval of android versions.

Cordova Docs:
[Here is the table of different intervals](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html)